# Calculating datagridview as 0.5

Tags: vb.net

I have a datagridview with columns, I want to have a column that only adds 0.5 values but i can't seem to make it work.

Here is the code i have at the moment. thanks

```
 Private Sub Button6_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button6.Click
    Dim sum As Integer = 0
    For Each row As DataGridViewRow In DataGridView1.Rows
        If row.IsNewRow Then
            Exit For
        End If
        Dim number As Integer
        If Integer.TryParse(row.Cells("HalfDay").Value.ToString(), number) Then
            sum += number
        End If
    Next
    TextBox3.Text = sum.ToString()
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the current result or problem?

Comment: at the moment it adds whole numbers in the column, but what i need it to perform is calculate 0.5 + 0.5 so on and so on in the column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the additional information.

I believe the problem is that you want to do a `Decimal.TryParse()` instead of the `Integer.TryParse()` since integers only deal with whole numbers in .NET. You'll also want your `sum` and `number` variables to be a decimal to handle the change.

Comment: ok thanks, i will try it out when i get back into the office.

Comment: If you'd like to continue seeking an answer, please post an update at the bottom of your current question with what you have tried this time around.